# What is this c++ template syntax

Tags: c++, templates

In STL, I saw the following template definitions:

```
template <class _Ty>
struct remove_reference {
    using type                 = _Ty;
    using _Const_thru_ref_type = const _Ty;
};

template <class _Ty>
struct remove_reference<_Ty&> {
    using type                 = _Ty;
    using _Const_thru_ref_type = const _Ty&;
};
```

I have not seen `struct remove_reference<_Ty&>` this kind of syntax before at the definition of a struct. The syntax similar to this that I know is that when you create a new object e.g. `remove_reference<_Ty&> newObject`.

What does it mean to use `struct remove_reference<_Ty&>` at the definition of a struct?

This is not like a template specialization either, as it will resemble the format like `template<> struct remove_reference<_Ty&>`. Could anyone let me know what c++ feature this is, and the official link, please?

Please note: this is not a duplicate of the common specification questions. As they didn't discuss the syntax of keeping both the generic template parameter on the top and in the struct at the same time.

Comment: Please look for the term *specialization*.

Comment: more specifically [partial template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization)

Comment: Thanks guys, for template specialization does it take the form of 
template<> struct remove_reference<_Ty&>
instead of template<class _Ty> struct remove_reference<_Ty&>?

Comment: @AnningWuwang -- no, that's what you do when you have a **specific** type: `template <> struct X<int> ...`; the compiler knows what `int` means. When you want to use a **generic** type with a qualifier you have to have a name for the generic type, hence, `template <class Ty> struct X<Ty&> ...`. If you write `template <> struct X<Ty&>...` the compiler doesn't know what the name `Ty` refers to.

Comment: I see, thank you @PeteBecker! Do you have any official links say a link on cppreference.com introducing this syntax I can have a good read about?